# Entity framework ForeignKeyAttribute on property … on type … is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I get this error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'SubdivisionsHOA' on type
>   'HealthOfAustralia.DAL.Models.ContentArticleHOAsubdivision' is not
>   valid. The foreign key name 'SubdivisionHOAId' was not found on the
>   dependent type 'HealthOfAustralia.DAL.Models.SubdivisionHOA'. The Name
>   value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Here are the model classes:

```
public partial class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long ContentArticleId { get; set; }
    public short SubdivisionHOAId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentArticleId")]
    public virtual ContentArticleHOA ContentArticleHOA { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubdivisionHOAId")]
    public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubdivisionHOA
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("TopTierDivisionHOA")]
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual TopTierDivisionHOA TopTierDivisionHOA { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose `one to many` relation and use the following code:

```
public class ContentArticleHOAsubdivision
{
     ...Comment this
     //public short SubdivisionHOAId { get; set; }
     ...
     [InverseProperty(" create property for ContentArticleHOAsubdivision on SubdivisionHOA")]
     public virtual ICollection<SubdivisionHOA> SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
}
```

or `one to one` with this one:

```
[ForeignKey("SubdivisionHOA")]
public short SubdivisionHOAId { get; set; }

public virtual SubdivisionHOA SubdivisionsHOA { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is pretty clear:  you specified `SubdivisionHOAId` as the foregin key property name on the `SubdivisionHOA` class, which doesn't exist. You probably meant to type `Id`.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, **or placed on a navigation property** and specify the associated foreign key name.

And from the Name property's description:

> If you add the ForeigKey attribute to a navigation property, you should specify **the name of the associated foreign key(s)**. If a navigation property has multiple foreign keys, use comma to separate the list of foreign key names.

It's this second use that applies here. `SubdivisionsHOA` is considered a navigation property so the compiler looks for a foreign key named `SubdivisionHOAId` on the `SubdivisionHOA` class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Panagiotis, however I think the [ForeignKey] attribute refers to a property within the same class that is acting as the foreign key for linking to the other table, so it refers to public short SubdivisionHOAId { get; set; } in ContentArticleHOAsubdivision

Comment: The compiler's error message disagrees, and you can't argue with the compiler

Comment: Doing what you suggest results in the entity framework trying to link Id in ContentArticleHOAsubdivision as the foreign key to SubdivisionHOA which is wrong, so I'm completely stuck :(